# Yarn installation on windows

Tags: yarnpkg

I am trying to upgrade yarn package on windows by doing npm install -g yarn but it keeps coming back with the following comments:

changed 1 package, and audited 3 packages in 996ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

What does it mean and anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upldate yarn then you have to run:

```sh
npm i -g yarn@latest
```

After this command try to run:

```
yarn -v
```

If you see it is showing old version then reboot your computer and check the version again. Hopefully it will help you.

Note if you install yarn via npm on windows for security reasons you can't use yarn using Powershell unless you turn off the Powershell security. But you can use the cmd to run yarn commands. So I'd suggest you to use cmd instead of turning off Powershell security